# Q: How to get "invoice_id" value after transaction execute in PayPal REST SDK?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I have done paypal subscription integration with paypal-node-sdk, after transaction complete how can i get invoice Id.

Do i need to generate the Invoice ID after transaction complete ? if i generate and change the invoice to paid status, then how the excute transaction and paypal invoice id matches ?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link for Fully updates an invoice, by ID. In the JSON request body, include a complete invoice object

[invoices_update](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/v1/#invoices_update)

Comment: Thanks, I understand to make invoice ID, But do i have to make the api to get the Invoice ID after transaction complete or else after transaction execute will i get ..?

Comment: There is no need to create invoice id at your side paypal will provide you when you draft and update invoice.

Comment: No, am asking after transaction execute function complete we have to make a call for invoiceID then in the response will get the InvoiceID. am i right..?